# Primefaces poll don't start

Tags: primefaces

I`m sorry for my bad english
I´ve created a Primeface p:datatable from my Database,
works fine, but it should refresh after some time.
I want to use Primefaces functions and i think poll is the right for me,
but when I start, there occurs no error and nothing happens.
Can someone help me?
Here is the XHTML-Code:

```
<p:poll id="pollId" interval="4" listener="#{tableView.reload()}"
        update=":tableForm" autoStart="true" />
```

and in my Backbean:

```
public void reload(){
    System.out.println("run for a test");
}
```

It seems to be, that the function is not even called, but why?
For now, I just want to run it for a test, the reload() funtion should load every 4 seconds, but nothing happens.

Comment: In the end I want to do something like this: tableService = new TableList()

Comment: Can you please provide what error you are getting after you "start"? Also, please what exactly is this "start"? Deployment, page load or anything else? As last hint, try to call the poll listener like this: `listener="#{tableView.reload()}"`

Comment: the JBOSS-Server starts correctly, the application is deployed and runs fine. The page has been displayed correctly. With "start" I mean that the poll-function should beginn the intervall automatically to update the site after 30 minutes, by calling the function reload(), but the poll don't even load this function, even with round brackets. It is strange, because it returns no error, and the poll doesn't work